# AB testing with R

Tags: r

I'm new with AB testing and i want to do this with R (free and easy to learn software).

Can anyone help with sample code in R for AB testing?

Thanks
Ariel

Comment: I don't know what is AB testing but this thread has been automatically linked to yours: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/a-b-testing-in-python-or-r

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do AB testing in R you should use Fishers exact test.

Given that you have the data (two groups A and B) along with the number of people who did what you wanted them to in each group (Yes and No).

```
m<-matrix(c(10,30,20,10), 2,2)
rownames(m)<-c("A", "B")
colnames(m)<-c("Yes", "No")
fisher.test(m)
```

Which will give you the following output:

```
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  m
p-value = 0.0006557
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05135257 0.52911468
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.1716418
```

Which shows you that the groups A and B are significantly different. :)

There you go, AB testing in R.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform a Pearson's Chi-squared Test with chisq.test function.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/chisq.test.html